# In the lifecycle scope with two StateFlow observers, only first works

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle, kotlin-stateflow

It seems to me that I do not quite understand something. Could you please explain to me why when I use this example, only the first collect works for me.

```
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.test1.flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED).collect {
            Log.i("Log_tag", it)
        }
        viewModel.test2.flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED).collect {
            Log.i("Log_tag", it)
        }
    }
```

or if i call them like this:

```
  lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
            viewModel.test1.collect {
                Log.i("Log_tag", it)
            }
            viewModel.test2.collect {
                Log.i("Log_tag", it)
            }
        }
    }
```

But if I call them in different coroutines, then they work both, as here:

```
  lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.test1.flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED).collect {
            Log.i("Log_tag", it)
        }

    }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.test2.flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED).collect {
            Log.i("Log_tag", it)
        }
    }
```

viewModel:

```
class ForecastViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val _test1 = MutableStateFlow("")
private val _test2 = MutableStateFlow("")
val test1 = _test1.asStateFlow()
val test2 = _test2.asStateFlow()

fun getTest() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _test1.value = "test1"
        _test2.value = "test2"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting a `StateFlow` never finishes, because StateFlows don't terminate.

This is pretty much expected.  Launching concurrent collectors is the right thing.

(I wonder if they could "override" `StateFlow.collect` to have return type `Nothing` to make that clearer.)

Comment: So the only way to go about this it to launch the coroutines or collect the flows in a different coroutine scope? Because I seem to be having this issue, but collecting them in a different coroutineScope seems to work. What about adding calling them in a suspend function and calling the suspend functions inside the coroutineScope. Would it make sense to do that or would it even work? This is my first time encountering this, so I'm still quite new to it